# How to build expo app with Xcode, without metro

Tags: ios, xcode, expo

I have an expo app, and I want to build it using Xcode to install it on my iPhone, without having to upload it to the store or something like that (because it's only for me and testing purposes)

I ran the command "npx expo prebuild" to create the android/ and iOS/ folders.
The project opens just fine in Xcode (and builds too), but I need to leave the metro terminal that Xcode opens for the app to work

But, I need it to works without having to connect to my pc (just like the build for android would work)

Comment: Create a debug build & install IPA. You can use appcenter to for internal distribution

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain how do I create a debug build on xcode? It seems that appcenter is paid

Comment: appcenter is free. You can archive & then distribute build from xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your Expo app on your physical device without using the Expo Go app and an Expo server, you would need to create a standalone app binary (an IPA file for iOS).

This process involves "ejecting" from the managed Expo workflow to gain more control over the build process. Here's the general process:

- Run expo eject in your project directory. This will create native iOS and Android project directories and configuration files.
- For iOS, you'll now have an ios folder in your project directory. You can open this in Xcode by navigating to the directory and opening the .xcworkspace file.
- From Xcode, you can run your app on a connected device by selecting the device from the target device list and clicking the "play" button.

Please note: In order to install the app on a physical device, you'll still need an Apple Developer account, even if it's just the free version. You'll have to sign your app with a development certificate. The app will also only run as long as the development certificate is valid, which is typically 7 days for a free Apple Developer account. After this period, you'll need to re-sign and re-install the app.

If you're looking for a way to run your app on your physical device indefinitely without an Apple Developer account, unfortunately, this is not possible due to Apple's policies.

Answer (score 0):

An alter way to install without purchasing 99dolars membership is getting your UIDI Registration from [www.udidregistrations.com](http://www.udidregistrations.com) and you'll be able to install your app in a specific device for way much cheaper price, hope that helps.